# Arzela Ascoli-Values in Banach Space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Suppose we have a sequence of continuous functions $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}:[a,b]\rightarrow X$ where $X$ is some Banach space. I want to deduce that there is a subsequence $(f_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ which converges uniformly to some $f^*\in C([a,b],X)$ or $f^*\in C([a,b],X')$, where $X$ is compactly embedded into $X'$.

In the case $X=\mathbb{R^d}$ we can use the classical Arzela-Ascoli theorem and we only need to show:
-$f_n$ is uniformly bounded in $n$ 
-$f_n$ is uniformly equicontinuous

Are these two conditions sufficient if $X$ is a Banach space? If so can anyone point to a reference?

The only reference I found is in the case where we replace $[a,b]$ by a compact Hausdorff space and choose $X$ to be a metric space.
In this case equicontinuity, pointwise relatively compactedness and closedness of the set $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is needed and both pointwise relatively compactedness and closedness seem tricky. Pointwise relatively compactness could be solved if we have $X$ compactly embedded into $X'$ and use the uniformly boundedness, but I don't know how to deal with the closedness.

Why is the closedness not needed in the $\mathbb{R}^d$ case?

Comment: I don't see how it could be true. Take for $X$ an infinite dimensional Hilbert space and $(e_n)$ an orthonormal family. Let $f_n(t) = e_n$ for all $t\in [a,b]$. Then $f_n$ cannot converge in a strong sense.

Comment: That's a great example. $f_n$ wouldn't converge in $C_{[a,b]}X$ but it could still converge in $C_{[a,b]}X'$ right?

Comment: You only need pointwise closedness to get a *compact* subset of $C([a,b];X)$. If you only want to have a *pre-compact* subset of $C([a,b];X)$, which seems to be the case here, then pointwise closedness is not needed.

Comment: the generalized version of Arzelá-Ascoli theorem (given by Fréchet) says that if $K$ and $X$ are metric spaces, with $K$ compact and $G\subset C(K,X)$ then $G$ is precompact if and only if $G$ is equicontinuous and $G(K)\subset Y$ for some precompact $Y\subset X$